SAP S4/HANA login via scripting - no longer showing "SAP GUI Logon" dialog
I use VBA scripting to automate several data extracts from SAP S4/HANA.  I invoke a Windows client using the following command:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapshcut.exe" -sysname="<sysname>" -client=<client num>

Until last week, this command popped up a small dialog box which allowed my script to enter a user ID and password.  Now, this dialog box isn't appearing.  Instead, I get the screen below.

The error at the bottom of this screen is new, but I can enter a user ID and password here and execute my scripts.  However, my automations are now broken because they are looking for a dialog box that I believe is titled "SAP GUI Logon".
I know of nothing that changed, but my Corporate systems are constantly changing settings on my computers and in SAP.
What can I do to get my login dialog box back?

@SandraRossi, I'm wanting to pop up the dialog box itself.  From the command in my question, I am not providing a password.  Is there a registry setting to show the dialog box as well?

I have since learned that this dialog box appears if I log into an ECC system but not the S4 system that I am trying to connect to.  Does this mean that the issue is with the system, or my client settings?

I guess you mean this popup (possibly the title has changed due to the SAP GUI version used):

I don't see a reason why one system (ECC) displays it and another one (S/4HANA) doesn't, except if the S/4HANA connection route doesn't support the only indication -sysname, maybe you need now to indicate -gui (long name: -guiparm).
You may run the program sapgui.exe to see these routes:

-gui examples from the SAP note 103019:

-gui="sapserver 10" or -gui="sapserver 10" specifies the target system using start parameters of SAPGUI.EXE. (host and instance number)
-gui="/R/<sapsystemID>/G/<group>" specifies a logon using system name and logon group.
-gui="[/H/<saprouter1[/S/saprouterservice1][...]
-gui="/M/<messageserver>/S/<service>/G/<group>" specifies a load balancing logon by specifying the message server and the logon group.
-gui="/R/<sapsystemID>/M/<messageserver>/G/<group>" specifies a load balancing logon by specifying the system name, the message server and the logon group.


Thank you for this.  I spent some time trying to determine the needed parameters, and could not do so.  I will file a help desk ticket with our SAP team.  If I can resolve the issue using your helpful answer, I will mark your response as accepted.
